# Route command output

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, networking, routes

Route command output:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.10    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
$
```

From the above output the following are the doubts I have:

1. What is 0.0.0.0 means in destination and gateway column
2. If the packet is sent from 192.168.2.36 ip, what is the gateway for that. It use 192.168.2.10 or 0.0.0.0
3. Lets consider I have one more network with ip 192.168.1.0. If the packet is sent from any of the host from this network, what is the
   gateway for that ip.
4. What is default gateway.

Answer (score 3):

1. On the first line, 0.0.0.0 in `Genmask` means there is no mask, i.e. in combination with a `destination` of 0.0.0.0, it means all destinations (the default gateway definition). On the second line, 0.0.0.0 in the `gateway` column means no gateway (directly connected the local subnet).
2. When routing, it does not matter where you are sending *from*, but where you are sending *to*.
3. Packets sent to network 192.168.1.0 will be routed using gateway 192.168.2.10, since the first line is the only one that matches destination 192.169.1.0.
4. 192.168.2.10 (see answer 1).

Comment: Mind you, this question (and answer) would have been better on [Super User](http://http://superuser.com/).

Comment: For 1.0 network gateway is 2.10. Like that what is the gateway for the network 192.168.2.0.

Comment: The second line indicates that you are directly connected to network 192.168.2.0 (that is the subnet the network interface is connected to - therefore no routing is necessary, no gateway, packets are sent directly from your system to another system on the same subnet).